# VBA filter from a range that have been set

Tags: vba, filter, range, autofilter

I am trying to use Autofilter command. I want the range to be a table that I have set as following

```
Dim myTable As Range
Set myTable = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```

So I thought when I want to filter, I should be doing something like

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("myTable").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="AUGUST"
```

But there seems to be an error saying "Subscript out of range"

Maybe I am wrong about the range part. Because when I use eg:range("A1:K500"), it works fine. But I really prefer it to be in the range of CurrentRegion since this data might be in different range every month, so it would be too much work to change the range in VBA manually everytime.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a table named  "myTable", in the active sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("myTable").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="AUGUST"
```

with

```
myTable.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="AUGUST"
```

If there is a table named "myTable" you can use your above code, not needing of any preliminary range set. If there is only one table, you can use:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="AUGUST"
```

Comment: @Asifa.K: Glad I could help! But you did not say which variant worked...  Besides that, we here when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...

Comment: I see. Sorry, very new to this :D The first variant worked for me. Since I only have one table in my excel